# Discord.Net DependencyMap issue

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am having issues creating a dependency map as I thought it is a part of `Discord.Commands`. All I could find was samples and bots already using the same line I am but my visual studio thinks it is an error.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Discord.Commands;

namespace UCS_bot
{
    public class Program
    {

    public static void Main(string[] args) =>
        new Program().Start().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    private DiscordSocketClient client;
    private CommandHandler handler;

    public async Task Start()
    {
        client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig() { LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info });

        var token = "******";
        await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
        await client.StartAsync();

        var map = new DependancyMap();
        map.Add(client);
```

It keeps saying I am missing using directive but I am 99% sure it is `Discord.Commands`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Specifically which line is saying you are missing a `using` directive?

Comment: Right-click, Quick Actions and Refactorings..., Select the using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a typo, it should be `DependencyMap` instead of `DependancyMap`.

https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Commands.DependencyMap.html

Comment: Your link now gets a 404

Comment: @ZoomVirus - It looks like `DependencyMap` was removed from `Discord.Commands` in a newer version - https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Commands.html